# Laravel 5.4 doesn't access the css in live server

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My application in the live server cannot access the `styles.css` but works on the local server. Following image shows the screenshot of the app in the local server.

[image: Production server image]

But the following image from the live server. It doesn't show the jumbotron background image.

[image: Live server image]

I have renamed the `server.php` file in Laravel root folder to `index.php`. And added the public folder `.htaccess` to the root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And `public` folder permissions as follows.

[image: public folder permissions]

And my storage folder permissions as follows.

[image]

When I look at the apache error log, I can see the following errors.

```
Tue Apr 18 22:19:57.092337 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1664] [client 162.243.22.209:50174] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:22:06.708959 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1667] [client 162.243.22.209:50190] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:23:13.421368 2017] [:error] [pid 2449] [client 162.243.22.209:50192] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#3 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#4 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
[Tue Apr 18 22:23:13.422505 2017] [:error] [pid 2449] [client 162.243.22.209:50192] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_h in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
[Tue Apr 18 22:25:14.356282 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1665] [client 162.243.22.209:50200] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:25:18.269469 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1666] [client 162.243.22.209:50202] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:27:07.872258 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1668] [client 162.243.22.209:50204] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:28:25.159874 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1667] [client 162.243.22.209:50206] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:32:38.827488 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1664] [client 162.243.22.209:50212] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:32:49.900769 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1665] [client 162.243.22.209:50214] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:33:29.070301 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1666] [client 162.243.22.209:50216] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 18 22:33:35.622783 2017] [:error] [pid 1668] [client 162.243.22.209:50218] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#3 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#4 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
[Tue Apr 18 22:33:35.623722 2017] [:error] [pid 1668] [client 162.243.22.209:50218] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_h in /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
[Tue Apr 18 22:37:41.752617 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 1665] [client 162.243.22.209:50234] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/admin/web/9url.cf/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://9url.cf/public/
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your storage folder doesn't have write permissions.

Comment: @Daan But I already set permissions to 777 storage folder and laravel.log file.

Comment: When I visit http://9url.cf it shows the image. Try emty your cache, disable addons that block content, etc. Also, it should be "Shorten your URL".

Comment: @SaeedPrez It's because as a workaround I added the styles as inline styling. And thank you very much for showing that error. This is a project to learn Laravel.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I visit your website and it's working fine. If you want help, why do a workaround and hide the problem? The Apache error is basically saying the index is not found and your options settings has `-Indexes` which prevent Apache from generating directory index.

Comment: Also, you can check out Laravel's default .htaccess at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess ... there is usually no need to change that.

Comment: I removed the workaround which is inline styling. And here is how I import css. <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/styles.css')}}"/> Ok. I will check the link.

Comment: I replaced the .htaccess file ( with the link you provided) but it is still the same.

Comment: Alright, looks like your styles.css file is empty. Can you verify that it is not empty on the production server?

Answer (score 0):

Check Following things

1.css url (may be wrong URL)

2.check .htaccess file(css blocked or Not)

3.index.php file

4.storage/ ---> permissions(chmod 777 -R)

6.add css into public folder (we can use every where project)

7.apache mod_rewrite should enabled (http server)

**Then sure will work.**